# ffmpeg detects audio streams in random order

Tags: ffmpeg

I have program which connects to a live MPEG-TS stream and feeds it to ffmpeg, which converts it to MPEG-DASH.

The input TS has three audio PIDs. (The exact audio PIDs will be different depending on the program ID and stream source so cannot be hard coded into a command line). For example:

```
0x67 Spanish Dubbed Audio "spa/Main Audio"
0x68 Original Audio "qaa/Main Audio"
0x69 Descriptive Audio for visually impaired
```

The player, using `dash.js`, in the web browser has a menu to select which audio track to select.

However, depending on when the connection is made to the MPEG-TS stream, ffmpeg enumerates the audios in different and seemingly random orders.  Seems the audio tracks are assigned in the output by ascending "input stream" index. For example:

```
Output Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:18 (mpeg2video) -> scale (graph 0)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:9  -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:13 -> #0:2 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:17 -> #0:3 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
```

is assigned after scanning the input assigns spa/spa/qaa:

```
  Stream #0:9[0x67](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:13[0x69](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (visual impaired) (descriptions)
  Stream #0:17[0x68](qaa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Running it a few more times, the input detection is always different:

```
  Stream #0:8[0x69](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (visual impaired) (descriptions)
  Stream #0:15[0x68](qaa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
  Stream #0:17[0x67](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  
  Stream #0:10[0x68](qaa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
  Stream #0:17[0x67](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:22[0x69](spa): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (visual impaired) (descriptions)
```

How can I get `ffmpeg` to create a consistent mapping of input-to-output?  Ideally, by incremental PID number.

**EDIT I**

I don't think it is really relevant to my question, but here is the command line for those interested...  `ffmpeg` reads from a pipe. The pipe is written to by my program receiving the feed.

```
ffmpeg -re -f mpegts -i pipe:10 -ignore_unknown \
  -map 0:p:510 -map -0:s -map -0:d \
  -filter_complex [p:510:v]scale=640:-1 -r 25 -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*1) \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 1M -x264-params scenecut=0 -threads 2 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ac 2 \
  -f dash -dash_segment_type mp4 -movflags +delay_moov \
    -seg_duration 2.000000 -frag_type duration -frag_duration 0.200000 \
    -index_correction 1 -target_latency 5 -window_size 10 -extra_window_size 5 \
    -remove_at_exit 1 -streaming 1 -ldash 1 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 \
    -write_prft 1 -avioflags direct -fflags +nobuffer+flush_packets \
    -format_options movflags=+cmaf -utc_timing_url \
    /web/be/time.php /var/ott/session_9733/master.mpd'
```

Answer (score 0):

A MPEG-TS is a transport stream i.e. a flowing stream, so the stream order is set by the order in which the demuxer encounters PES packets. This can't be changed.

---

What you could do, is replace the current positive map  `-map 0:p:510` with  `-map 0:p:510:v -map 0:p:510:a:m:language:qaa -map 0:p:510:a:m:language:spa`

I don't have a MPTS feed to work with, so I can't verify the syntax at present.

Comment: Thanks Gyan.  I suspected it was taking the audios as they arrived.  Since there are multiple streams with the same language and I'd like to enforce PID order, I've used the PID number in the mapping, like `-map 0:a:i:44`. Seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

From Gyan's answer, `ffmpeg` enumerates the streams as they see them.  Therefore, with an MPTS (multiprogram transport stream) there is no way to easily select a stream **and** enforce a particular ordering of the streams (based on PID number)

So the program has to first independently scan the TS to build a list of video and audio PIDs.  Then use those PIDs in a loop to construct the `ffmpeg` command line.

This is the constructed command line:

```
ffmpeg -re -loglevel verbose \
   -f mpegts -i inputFile.ts -ignore_unknown \
   -map 0:v:i:101 \
   -map 0:a:i:103 -metadata:s:a:0 title='Main' \
   -map 0:a:i:104 -metadata:s:a:1 title='Main' \
   -map 0:a:i:105 -metadata:s:a:2 title='Visual impaired commentary' \
   -map -0:s -map -0:d \
   -filter_complex [p:510:v]scale=640:-1 \
   -r 25 -force_key_frames expr:gte\(t,n_forced*1\) \
   -c:v libx264 -b:v 1M -x264-params scenecut=0 \
   -threads 2 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ac 2 \
   -f dash -dash_segment_type mp4 -movflags +delay_moov -seg_duration 2.000000 \
   -frag_type duration -frag_duration 0.200000 -index_correction 1 \
   -target_latency 5 -window_size 10 -extra_window_size 5 -remove_at_exit 1 \
   -streaming 1 -ldash 1 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -write_prft 1 \
   -avioflags direct -fflags +nobuffer+flush_packets -format_options movflags=+cmaf \
   -utc_timing_url /time.php \
   /tmp/master.mpd
```